# get count of events per item brand from GA4 in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get a breakdown of the number of times (event count) each brand occurred in an event (add_to_cart) in GA4 from BigQuery per day.

Essentially the output I am looking for:

| Date | Event | Brand | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | add_to_cart | Nike | 42 |
| 2022-05-01 | add_to_cart | Adidas | 32 |
| 2022-05-02 | add_to_cart | Nike | 47 |
| 2022-05-03 | add_to_cart | Nike | 23 |

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  event_date,
  event_name,
  (SELECT item_brand FROM unnest(items)) AS brand
FROM `bigquery-xxxxxx.analytics_xxxxxxxxx.events_2022-5*`
WHERE event_name = 'add_to_cart'
```

However, it returns an error that I don't understand:

Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding LIMIT 1 to the subquery

```
SELECT
  event_date,
  event_name,
  (SELECT item_brand FROM unnest(items) LIMIT 1) AS brand
FROM `bigquery-xxxxxx.analytics_xxxxxxxxx.events_2022-5*`
WHERE event_name = 'add_to_cart'
```